# After adding options to 'select' dynamically, options don't show in Select/Dropdown on page

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

This is the dropdown which has only prefixed one (disabled) option

[image: ScreenCapture1]

Here is inspect, options can be seen here but not in UI.

[image: ScreenCapture2]

HTML Code:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
                    <select id="agentList" class="materialSelect">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Agent</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Agent</label>
                </div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var select = document.getElementById("agentList");

async function getAgents(url_) {

  await fetch(appSettings.url + url_, {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: "include",
  })
    .then(function (promise) {
      if (promise !== null) {
        if (promise.status === 200) {
          promise.json().then(function (data) {
            let agents = data.dropdown;
            data.forEach(value => {
              var opt = new Option(value, value);
              select.appendChild(opt);
            });
          });
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using materialize for select and initializing it by:

var select_= document.querySelectorAll('.materialSelect');
var instance = M.FormSelect.init(select_, "");

Comment: when you `disabled` there is no way you can see the options, so when you load options enable the dropdown... and disabled means disabled you can not interact with the component whatsoever...

Comment: @pavankumar but you see disabled is only for first option [Select Agent], not for all options. Check second picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you see in the UI is something that Materialize created when you initialized it, not the actual `<select>`. It won't update by itself when you change the original `<select>`.

To do what you want, you may need to destroy the instance and initialize it again:

```
// Already somewhere in your code
var select_ = document.querySelectorAll('.materialSelect');
var instance = M.FormSelect.init(select_, "");

// In the code you posted
await fetch(/* ... */)
      .then((promise) => {
        // ...
        data.forEach(value => {
          // ...
        });
        instance.destroy();
        instance = M.FormSelect.init(select_, "");
        // ...
      });
```

Comment: Destroying and initializing instance again worked. Thank you. :)